# Mocha Chai - using 'expect' and want to catch a 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, bdd, chai

I'm using [Mocha](http://mochajs.org/) and [Chai](http://chaijs.com/) as a Javascript testing suite.

I want to catch a 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' failure on on of my tests.

JS

```
function isEven(num){
   if (num === 0) {
      return true;
   } else if (num === 1) {
      return false;
   } else {
      return isEven(num - 2);
  }
}

// Example Call
isEven(-10); //Throws the error 'call stack'
```

I've been using [.throw](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/) but with no luck

```
expect(isEven(-1)).to.throw(ReferenceError, 'RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded');
```

or

```
expect(isEven(-1)).to.throw(err);
```

Not having an success with either.

I'm getting the following error in the terminal

```
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

the above details show `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Any help much appreciated

Comment: What is `isEven`? Please post relevant parts of your test file.

Comment: can you post the entire error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expect(...).to.throw()` requires a function (so Chai can run that function and catch any errors). You're passing it the result of a function (or at least trying to).

Try this:

```
expect(isEven.bind(null, -10)).to.throw(RangeError);
```

Which is somewhat similar to this:

```
function toTest() {
  isEven(-10);
}
expect(toTest).to.throw(RangeError);
```

Comment: Thanks @robertklep for the answer and the explanation (bind). +1

Comment: @fidev just to be clear, the "full" example is conceptually similar, but it's not an explanation on what `bind` does :)